# A "simplier" way of doing filter map operation on an Ordered dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an Ordered dict as follow :

```
MY_ORDERED_DICT = OrderedDict([
    ('table1', {
        'required': True,
        'col': OrderedDict([
            ('id',                 'aaa'),
            ('registration_date',       'aaa'),
            ('date_of_birth',           'aaa'),
        ])
    }),
    ('table2', {
        'required': True,
        'col': OrderedDict([
            ('product_id',      'aaa'),
            ('id',              'aaa'),
            ('datetime',        'aaa'),
            ('quantity',        'aaa'),
        ])
    }),
    ('table3', {
        'required': False,
        'col': OrderedDict([
            ('product_id',      'aaa'),
            ('brand',           'aaa'),
            ('name',            'aaa'),
        ])
    }),
    ('table4', {
        'required': False,
        'col': OrderedDict([
            ('campaign_id',     'aaa'),
            ('id',         'aaa'),
            ('datetime',  'aaa'),
        ])
    }),
    ('table5', {
        'required': False,
        'col': OrderedDict([
            ('c_id',     'aaa'),
            ('id',         'aaa'),
            ('datetime',  'aaa'),
        ])
    })
])
```

From this OrderedDict I want to extract the keys that have a columns (which is also an OrderedDict) field containing the strings `id` and `datetime`.

I do this as follow :

```
list(map(lambda element: element[0], filter(lambda cel:  {'id', 'datetime'}.issubset(set(cel[1]['col'])), MY_ORDERED_DICT.items())))
```

And it seems to work pretty well.
It does return :

```
['table2', 'table4', 'table5']
```

My problem is that I fear that somone will look at it and tells me that it's too complicated.

I'm looking for inspiration doing it in a more elegant manner.

Comment: This looks like a question more suitable for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `map()` and `filter()` when a list comprehension would be much clearer:

```
[
    key for key, value in MY_ORDERED_DICT.items()
    if {"id", "datetime"} <= value["col"].keys()
]
```

Note that the [keys dictionary view is also a set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), and you can test if a dictionary has a minimal set of keys with the `<=` or `>=` operators to determine if one is a subset or superset.

The above does the same work your code did and so produces the same output:

```
>>> [
...     key for key, value in MY_ORDERED_DICT.items()
...     if {"id", "datetime"} <= value["col"].keys()
... ]
['table2', 'table4', 'table5']
```

Comment: Extremely minor optimization (don't bother if the inputs are always going to be small anyway): Either construct the `set` (or `frozenset`) outside the `list` comp and reuse it, or (since it's just two things to test) test `if "id" in value["col"] and "datetime" in value["col"]`; as written, this rebuilds the `set` on every test.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes, for anything more than a few items in the dictionary that'd make a (small) difference. For other cases Python knows that a set literal like that can be treated as a constant, but in this case the AST optimizer isn't yet doing so, unfortunately.

Comment: key views are *set-like* because you can use operators like `<=`, but they are not sets.

Comment: @Booboo: Properly, they're `Set`s, in that they implement the `collections.abc.Set` interface.

Comment: @Booboo: they are not the `set` object, but they *are* sets! The implement the Set interface, as defined by [`collections.abc.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set). So they have a `.isdisjoint()` method, and support `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `&`, `|` and `^` operations with other sets.

Comment: The docs actually say: **For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class collections.abc.Set are available (for example, ==, <, or ^)**. I don't read that as being quite the same thing. `isinstance(MY_ORDERED_DICT.keys(), set) => False`

Comment: @Booboo: no, but `isinstance({}.keys(), collections.abc.Set)` and `isinstance(set(), collections.abc.Set)` both are true.